# Compiling .cu to .obj in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, cuda

Hi I have a Visual Studio solution for c++ with a .cu file (CUDA). This .cu implements a total of 7 functions. Each of these methods is also declared in the associated .h (test.cu -> test.h)

I've manage to compile the .cu into a .obj from visual studio with the compiler (nvcc.exe)

But when these functions are called the compiler gives me a unresolved external symbol

Now I know that the .obj generated from a CUDA file may not be "compatible" with the .obj generated from a C++ file, but is their some way to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the dumpbin tool in Visual Studio to check the obj file. It turns out it wasn't compiled correctly.